# importing NetBeans (Desktop Applications) into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, import

I'm wondering if I can import NetBeans projects (especially desktop applications) into Eclipse, that I have a NetBeans project which is a desktop application and I want to run it in Eclipse.. is that possible ? because I've searched, but no clear answers has showed up :(

Info : 
Platform : Mac OS 10.6.5
NetBeans : 6.5
Eclipse : 3.3.2
Java : JDK 1.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say Desktop Applications it sounds like you have designed the GUI using the Netbeans tools, and the generated Java files should run nicely, but you will not be able to edit them freely and expect Netbeans to like the revised files when you import them back.

SO, in other words, try and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, I've designed the GUI using NetBeans.. but I don't get it, what should I try ?

Comment: @user492194 - It's just that the GUI code that NetBeans modifies magically as you design the GUI will become "normal" code in Eclipse which you will have to edit manually if you want to change your GUI. Or you'll have to redesign your GUI from scratch.

Comment: Ok, I tried.. but the Eclipse does not recognize org.jdesktop.* , what should I do ?

Comment: @user492194, you are using a jdesktop library in your project.  Locate the jar file, right click and add it to the build path.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Netbeans and Eclipse are both just IDEs, so you can move code from one to the other easily. The folder structure they use may be a little different, but you should be able to just import the `.java` (or whatever other language you are using) files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project in eclipse and import the *.java files !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article on ["How to import NetBeans project into Eclipse"](http://article-stack.com/how-why/how-to-import-netbeans-project-into-eclipse.amty). I personally found method #2 to be more useful.